# Вопрос по JavaScript прокрутка по странице к айди

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Вопрос по прокрутке страницы к айдишнику. Делаю сайт на вордпрессе rosstroyservice.mcdir.ru
Нужно, чтобы при наличии определенной строки в url адрессе, а именно 'product-category', прокручивало страницу к определенному айдишнику, в моем случае #primary.
Вот, что удалось накопипастить моими кривыми клешнями из гугла.

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function($){
function slowScroll(id){
   console.log( id );
    var offset=0;
    $('html', 'body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(id).offset().top - offset
    }, 500);
    return false;
    
   };
``
 
slowScroll('#primary');
});
if (window.location.href.indexOf('product-category') > -1){
   console.log( "category!" );
   slowScroll('#primary');
   
  };
```

Но так как я деревянный по пояс в написании скриптов, у меня ничего не работает(ну хоть ошибки не выдает)). Вообщем хэлп! Что неправильно у меня?

Comment: Ну как же не выдаёт? А `slowScroll is not defined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вызываете функцию, которую определили внутри другой функции из глобального контекста.
Она там не определена(к тому же, к моменту вызова она ещё не определена нигде).
Перенесите вызов внутрь функции:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function slowScroll(selector) {
    $('html, body')
       .stop()
       .animate({scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top}, 500);
  };

  if (window.location.href.indexOf('product-category') > -1) {
    slowScroll('#primary');
  };

});
```

Также, селектор элемента('html, body') должен быть одной строкой.

Comment: Спс за помошь vp_arth. где тебя лайкнуть брат?